# Output shows values of Context from function not using context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

/* context.js */
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "f1":
      return Object.assign(action.payload, state);
    case "reset":
      return init(!action.payload);
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function init(resetKey) {
  return {
    resetKey,
    obj1: {
      name: "obj2",
      value: [],
    },
    obj2: {
      name: "obj2",
      value: [],
    },
    f1: ({ obj1, obj2 }) => {},
    reset: () => {},
  };
}

const Context = createContext(init(true));

function ContextProvider(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, true, init);

  function f1Handler(newObj) {
    dispatch({
      type: "f1",
      payload: newObj,
    });
  }

  function resetHandler() {
    dispatch({
      type: "reset",
      payload: state.resetKey,
    });
  }

  const context = {
    resetKey: state.resetKey,
    obj1: state.obj1,
    obj2: state.obj2,
    f1: f1Handler,
    reset: resetHandler,
  };
  return <Context.Provider value={context}>{props.children}</Context.Provider>;
}

/* App.js */
const Caller = () => {
  let { f1 } = useContext(Context);
  let value = Test();
  useEffect(() => {
    f1(value);
  }, []);
  return null;
};

function Test() {
  let obj1 = {
    name: "obj1",
    value: [1, 2, 3],
  };
  let obj2 = {
    name: "obj2",
    value: [4, 5, 6],
  };
  let rtn = {
    obj1,
    obj2,
  };
  console.log(rtn, obj1, obj2);
  return rtn;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ContextProvider>
        <Caller />
      </ContextProvider>
      <h1> Loaded </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```json
{obj1: {…}, obj2: {…}}
  f1: ({ obj1, obj2 }) => {}
  obj1: {name: 'obj2', value: Array(0)}
  obj2: {name: 'obj2', value: Array(0)}
  reset: () => {}
  resetKey: true
  [[Prototype]]: Object
 
{name: 'obj1', value: Array(3)}
  name: "obj1"
  value: (3) [1, 2, 3]
  [[Prototype]]: Object
 
{name: 'obj2', value: Array(3)}
  name: "obj2"
  value: (3) [4, 5, 6]
  [[Prototype]]: Object

------------------------

{obj1: {…}, obj2: {…}}
  obj1: {name: 'obj1', value: Array(3)}
  obj2: {name: 'obj2', value: Array(3)}
  [[Prototype]]: Object
 
{name: 'obj1', value: Array(3)}
  name: "obj1"
  value: (3) [1, 2, 3]
  [[Prototype]]: Object
 
{name: 'obj2', value: Array(3)}
  name: "obj2"
  value: (3) [4, 5, 6]
  [[Prototype]]: Object
```

Why are the first objects in the console not equal?
Or more specifically why is the function and reset from the context in the frist output? How does it get passed and why?

Furthermore why does the second second object in the first log not equal the obj1 inside of rtn even if it was retrievied from there?

This is confusing me. If you remove the use Effect the first output disappears, but the Effect should be triggering the second. So maybe the first is then correct and the second disappears. But that is not what confuses me. I am just confused by the values of the context appearing inside a function that does not consume the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally figured out where the issue comes from. It is hard to understand why the console.log is affected though, but maybe that is because it is far slower than the code itself.

`Object.assign()` in my reducer (context.js) has swaped source and target. This leads to the source being modiefied. Though the target stays the same.